# Linq to SQL update not updating data, no exceptions c#

Tags: linq-to-sql, exception, c#-4.0

I am trying to update a record in the database using `Linq-to-SQL`.

```
DataContext db = new DataContext();
table t = (from c in db.table
           where c.id == id
           select c).SingleOrDefault();
```

I check to see if a record is returned or not and do an `INSERT` or `UPDATE` based on the results.

```
if(t != null)
{
    t.column0 = data0;
    t.column1 = data1;
    t.column2 = data2
}
else
{
    table n = new table();
    n.column0 = data0;
    n.column1 = data1;
    n.columns2 = data2;
    db.table.InsertOnSubmit(n);
}

try
{
    db.SubmitChanges();
}
catch(ChangeConflictException e)
{
    return e.Message;
}
```

I've stepped through it in debug, the exception is never thrown and the database never gets updated. I'm still new with Linq so I figure I'm missing something...any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, no `PK` on table. I knew it was a n00b problem :P